# There cannot exist any non constant continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness

Prove that there cannot exist any non constant continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$.

If there exist such an continuous function , it will map interval to a connected subset  of $\mathbb{Q}$. I am unable to imagine connected subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ to for proving the above statement. Can anyone help me in this? Thanks.

Comment: Your insight about connected subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ is good.  The only connected subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ are singletons, sets with one point.  It follows that a function with such an image... is a constant function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider any subset $A$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ which has at least two points, say $a, b$, with $a < b$. Then between $a$ and $b$ there is an irrational number. This tells you that $A$ is disconnected.

Comment: Between $1/2$ and $1$ lies for instance $\pi/4$. The sets $U = \{ x \in \mathbb{Q} : x < \pi/4\}$ and $V = \{ x \in \mathbb{Q} : x > \pi/4\}$ are open in $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathbb{Q} = U \cup V$, so your set $A$ splits as $A = (A \cap U) \cup (A \cap V)$. (This was a response to a now deleted comment.)

Answer (score 0):

A function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb Q$ is in particular *also* a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ -- and if you unfold the definition of continuity you will see that the function is still continuous when viewed as $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Now assume that there is $f(x_1)\ne f(x_2)$ and apply the intermediate value theorem ...